# rails3 group by issue with sqlite3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Following query should work but it is not working.

```
class Keyword
  def self.popular_queries
    t = Time.now
    relation = Keyword.where(:created_at => (t.beginning_of_day..t.end_of_day))
    relation = relation.group(:name)
    relation = relation.select("name, COUNT(id) AS count_value")
    relation.to_a
  end
 end
```

result is following without count value

```
[#<Keyword name: "a">, #<Keyword name: "b">, 
#<Keyword name: "c">, #<Keyword name: "d">]
```

keywords table has only two columns `name` and id.

Solution is

```
  def self.popular
    t = Time.now
    relation = Keyword.where(:created_at => (t.beginning_of_day..t.end_of_day))
    relation = relation.group(:name)
    relation = relation.select("name, created_at, count(*) as c1")
    sql = relation.to_sql
    self.connection.select_all(sql)
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `Keyword` model doesn't know what `count_value` is and you're instantiating a bunch of `Keyword` instances based on an SQL query. When your instances are created, they see `count_value` in the data they're handed but they ignore it as they have no `count_value` property.

If you want to run arbitrary SQL and get back simple data, you should be using [`select_rows`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html#method-i-select_rows) or similar low level methods.

Comment: sorry. I should have said it has two columns. name and id.

Comment: notice that sql is not blowing up. It is not showing the valid result.

Comment: @Nadal: What is the SQL that is being produced behind the scenes?

Comment: switched to mysql and same problem. Keyword.popular
  Keyword Load (1.8ms)  SELECT name, created_at, count(*) as c1 FROM `keywords` WHERE (`keywords`.`created_at` BETWEEN '2011-04-14 04:00:00' AND '2011-04-15 03:59:59') GROUP BY name
 => [#<Keyword name: "a", created_at: "2011-04-14 17:55:15">, #<Keyword name: "b", created_at: "2011-04-14 17:55:15">, #<Keyword name: "c", created_at: "2011-04-14 17:55:15">, #<Keyword name: "d", created_at: "2011-04-14 17:55:15">]

Comment: thanks. that did it. I updated question with the answer. I will see if rails core will take  patch to blow up if a column is not matching.